# POSTGRESQL: Enumerate with the same number if having the same criteria

Tags: postgresql, partition, row-number, enumerate

What I have

```
id | value
1 | foo
2 | foo
3 | bah
4 | bah
5 | bah
6 | jezz
7 | jezz
8 | jezz
9 | pas
10 | log
```

What I need: 
Enumerate rows as in the following example

```
id | value | enumeration
1 | foo | 1
2 | foo | 1
3 | bah | 2
4 | bah | 2
5 | bah | 2
6 | jezz | 3
7 | jezz | 3
8 | jezz | 3
9 | pas | 4
10 | log | 5
```

I've tried row_number with over partition. But this leads to another kind of enumeration.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` for that case:

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c4c3f41cfd678bb02105d1198eecddc1)

```
SELECT
    *,
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY value)
FROM
    mytable
```

`rank()` generates an ordered number to every element of a group, but it creates gaps (if there were 3 elements in the first group, the second group starting at row 4 would get the number 4). `dense_rank()` avoids these gaps.

Note, this orders the table by the `value` column alphabetically. So, the result will be: `blah == 1`, `foo == 2`, `jezz == 3`, `log == 4`, `pas == 5`.

---

If you want to keep your order, you need an additional order criterion. In your case you could use the `id` column to create such a column, if no other is available:

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3a6987c6c7c7185d9dee88e1c7682f3e)

First, use `first_value()` to find the lowest `id` per value group:

```
SELECT
    *,
    first_value(id) OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY id)
FROM
    mytable
```

This first value (`foo == 1`, `blah == 3`, ...) can be used to keep the original order when calculating the `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    value,
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY first_value)
FROM (
    SELECT
       *,
       first_value(id) OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY id)
    FROM
       mytable
) s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) That is exactly what I needed.